.NET 8.0 / EF Core update database in Docker
How do I accomplish db migration in the docker SQL Server? The Dockerfile is generated by the IDE. I need to add database migration in that DockerFile. Also, I need to expose the Swagger url outside of docker. My project is based on .NET 8.0.
Here is the DockerFile:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
USER app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 8081

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["QWiz.csproj", "."]
RUN dotnet restore "./QWiz.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "./QWiz.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "./QWiz.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "QWiz.dll"]


"I need to add database migration in that DockerFile" - can you please elaborate why? "Also, I need to expose the Swagger url outside of docker" - what have you tried and what exact problem you have with it? If you have mapped the port correctly then the swagger should be exposed as the rest of the app's endpoints.

How do I use "dotnet ef update database"? it seems not working. showing mssql connection failed. The swagger problem is solved. @GuruStron

Why do you want it in the docker container at all?

I just need to make a package (.NET  + mssql + react) to share with my people. They will up the docker and that's it.  @GuruStron

Please check out this answer. I would argue that it is better approach.

I made a project that does exactly this, I put it on my github to take a look. https://github.com/LeonardoQueres/Integration-Docker---.NET---SQL-SERVER
In the program.cs file add the line of code below.
builder.Services.AddHttpsRedirection(options =>
{
    options.RedirectStatusCode = Status308PermanentRedirect;
    options.HttpsPort = 3001;
});

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();

    var application = app.Services.CreateScope().ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();

    var pendingMigrations = await application.Database.GetPendingMigrationsAsync();
    if (pendingMigrations != null)
        await application.Database.MigrateAsync();
}

Update your dockerfile confirm the code below adding the migration lines.
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
USER app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 3000
EXPOSE 3001


FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["project/project.csproj", "project/"]
COPY ["Thunders_Repositories/Thunders_Repositories.csproj", "Thunders_Repositories/"]
COPY ["Thunders_Borders/Thunders_Borders.csproj", "Thunders_Borders/"]
COPY ["Thunders_UseCases/Thunders_UseCases.csproj", "Thunders_UseCases/"]
RUN dotnet restore "./project/project.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/project"
RUN dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef 
ENV PATH="$PATH:/root/.dotnet/tools"
RUN dotnet build "./project.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build
CMD dotnet ef database update --environment Development --project src/project_Repositories

FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "./project.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "project.dll"]

The code below belongs to docker-compose, update yours as needed.
services:
  project:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_HTTP_PORTS=3000
      - ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORTS=3001
    container_name: project
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}project
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: project/Dockerfile   
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
      - "3001:3001"
    volumes:
      - ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:/home/app/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro
      - ${APPDATA}/ASP.NET/Https:/home/app/.aspnet/https:ro
    networks:
      - compose-bridge
    depends_on:
      sqlserver:
        condition: service_healthy

  sqlserver:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-preview-ubuntu-22.04
    container_name: sqlserver    
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"
    environment:
      - SA_PASSWORD=passwork 'não pode ser uma senha fraca, sql nao funciona. nada de usar 123456 hehehehe'
      - ACCEPT_EULA= Y       
    volumes:
      - ./sqlserver/data:/var/opt/mssql/data
      - ./sqlserver/log:/var/opt/mssql/log   
    networks:
      - compose-bridge 
    healthcheck:
      test: /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P "leoQueres123" -Q "SELECT 1" -b -o /dev/null
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 3s
      retries: 10
      start_period: 10s  

volumes: 
  sqlserver:

networks:
  compose-bridge:
    driver: bridge

I hope I helped.
